# How can I compute the analytical formula for the number of patterns by using combination?

Tags: combinatorics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3DYt.jpg)A $4\times3$ matrix which has all elements empty, now I select any two consecutive elements until all elements are selected. I assign an index number ($1$ to $12$) to the matrix element, in one row there are only $1,2,3$ element and $3$ & $4$ are not consecutive. for example, if I select index $1$ & $2$ of the matrix, I get the first pattern. if I select $2$ & $3$ of the matrix, I get the second pattern, likewise $4$ & $5$ and so on. So, for the first-time selection of $2$ consecutive elements, there is an $8$ pattern (as shown in first_PIC). Now, I have $8$ patterns in which the first pattern has $1$ & $2$ index elements are fixed. now from this first pattern again I select $2$ consecutive elements, I get $6$ patterns (9 to 14 as shown in first_PIC). This process is repeated until all the possible patterns are created. In the figure, I created manually $80$ patterns for two consecutive elements but if I increase the size of the matrix, I cannot compute the number of patterns manually. I need an analytical formula for finding the total number of patterns. I attached a figure for the explanation. If anything you need to know let me know. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Now, we have 12 patterns in which the first pattern has 1 & 2 index elements are fixed."?

Comment: It might help to talk about the origin of this problem. Or explaining with a particular example, or a drawing, what you mean, because it's not clear right now.

Comment: It means after selecting 2 consecutive elements. the total number of different patterns is 12. For example, if we select in the first row, there are only 3 different patterns that are possible, which are (1, 2, is select and all rest 10 elements of the matrix are available) then (2 ,3) is selected and (3, 4).

Comment: Two things are unclear: (1) Does the order in which you select the elements matter? That is, if I first select $1\&2$, and then select $3\&4$, is that the same as first selecting $3\&4$, and then $1\&2$?

Comment: (2) You say you continue until **all** elements are selected. But if you choose $2\&3$ initially, then you will never be able to select $1$ or $4$. Is choosing $2\&3$ illegal, or do you mean you continue until you get stuck? Or can you stop at any time?

Comment: (1) No, the order does not matter. that is, 1&2, and then select 3&4 are same as 3&4 and 1&2.

Comment: (2) Choosing 2&3 are not illegal. We do not care about 1 & 4 because they are not adjacent. I select it because sequentially it is easy. Yes, we continue until we get stuck.

Comment: Thank you, Mike Earnest Sir

Comment: @Sahil Thank you for clarifying. In the future, you should clarify your question by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4192465/edit) the question, so people do not have to dig through the comments to figure out what you mean.

Comment: If my answer is incorrect, it is because I misunderstood what you are asking. Please **edit** your question so that what you are asking is completely clear. Feel free to reference my answer, and to specifically say why my answer is wrong. Furthermore, are you capable of solving the question for a $2\times 2$ matrix instead of $4\times 4$? If you can, it would be helpful to include a detailed solution of the $2\times 2$ case your edit, so we can see a fully worked out example of what you mean. I will not divulge my email.

Comment: Please do not edit my post to talk to me; you can comment here. To answer your question, refer to matrix number $12$ in your picture. You have two rows which are completely uncovered, one row where the left pair is covered, and one row where the right pair is covered. Clearly, completely uncovered rows are allowed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I got the point.  Sir, one more question, this formula also valid if I select 3 entries at a time instead of 2 entries. Can I convert this formula for the selection of any number of entries? with the condition, this entry size always less than or equal number of columns.  Thank you

Comment: Dear Sir, Mike Earnest, Thank you very much for your support. Today I am very much happy because of you. Because I was trying this problem for many days. Thank you once again.

Comment: You're welcome! It is not easy to generalize to $k$-at-a-time. For $3$-at-a-time, you would use the [tribonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) instead of FIbonacci, the tetranacci numbers for $4$-at-a-time, etc. I leave the rest to you. Remember, for all of these problems, the rows are independent of each other, so to solve for a $m\times n$ matrix, first solve it for a $1\times n$ matrix then raise to the $m^{th}$ power. If you ask the $k$-at-a-time question on math stack exchange, I advise asking the simple $1\times n$ case.

Comment: Sure, Sir, I will do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalize to counting arrangements in an $m\times n$ matrix. At any point in your process, each row in your matrix will be partially covered with selected pairs. Let $f_n$ be the number of ways to cover a single row in your matrix. For example, $f_3=3$, because a row with three entries $[1,2,3]$ can be completely uncovered, or the left two entries can be covered, or the right two entries can be covered.

Since each row is chosen independently, the number of ways to choose the full matrix is $(f_n)^m-1$. The $-1$ is there because we want to exclude the possibility where no pairs are chosen. You wouldn't need the $-1$ if you counted the "starting" combination in your picture.

All we need to do is compute $f_n$. It turns out that $f_n$ is exactly the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, defined by
$$
f_0=f_1=1, \qquad f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}\quad \forall n\in \mathbb Z
$$
For example,

| $n$ | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f_n$ | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 13 | 21 | 34 | 55 |

In your $4\times 3$ example, my formula predicts the number of patterns is $(f_3)^4-1=3^4-1=80$, which is what your example found. For $4\times 4$, there would be $(f_4)^4-1=5^4-1=624$ patterns.